# Python class или module

Tags: python

Что будет более эффективнее , быстрее и менее затратно в ресурсопотребления при обработке данные в python.
Обрабатывать данные через класс т.е. функционал программы  разнести по классам и обрабатывать их или  подключить его через import как модуль ?
Лично мое мнение с классами просто удобнее работать, когда ты глубоко в коде проще дотягиваться до нужных тебе атрибутов(переменных), методов и тд в отличии от использования import
Но меня больше интересует аспект кто занимает больше тактов  у процессора и памяти класс или import как модуль и как это отражается на быстродействие программы

Comment: Мне кажется, Python - это немного не тот язык, в котором надо думать о тактах процессора.